# Best plant, live or artificial, to include into a tropical fish tank

Tags: aquarium, aquatic-plants, tetra, plants

I have a tropical fish tank at the moment with:

- Tiger Tetras;
- Neon Tetras;
- 2 Catfish (I can't remember the exact species).

What plant would you suggest?

Comment: java fern or anubias, always.

Comment: How much lighting does the tank have?  Different plants require different amounts of light.  Also, what kind of substrate does the tank have, and how big is the tank?

Comment: Have to agree with Raystafarian. Foolproof plants in almost any tank.

Comment: Is there something specific you're wondering about plants? BEcause as it stands right now, I'm thinking the question is a bit too broad for us to answer.